# Creating a footer that stays at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have went through countless methods on the previously answered questions. I believe I followed this one (http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) to the t but I still cannot get my footer to stay at the bottom of the page. I know this has been asked countless times but I don't where to adjust my code. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

*HTML*

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eWLyoIY.png"/></a></div>
            <div class="chapter-logo"><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RPIvgdD.png"/></a></div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="">About ▾</a>
                    <ul class = "sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="history.html">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="brothers.html">Brothers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <li class = "dropdown"><a href="">Philanthropy ▾</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="kovacs.html">Kovacs Color Run</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="greekgod.html">Greek God</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                <li><a href="membership.html">Membership</a>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

            </ul>
        </nav>


<div class="index">
    <div class ="letter">
        <p><b><br>Welcome to the official website for the New York Iota chapter of Phi Kappa Psi at Binghamton 

University! Here you will be able to learn about us, and get a brief introduction to Greek Life at 

Binghamton. If you have any questions or simply want to learn more information, feel free contact us at 

any time.</b></br> 

        <br><b><font color ="#22674A">Carl Hashem (Chapter President)</b></font></br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "news-section">
<table class ="news">
    <tr>
    <td class ="social">
        <h4 align="center">Connect</h4>
        <a href ="http://instagram.com/phipsibing"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1GhbSOj.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/phi_psi_bing"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/oawoJtC.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/phipsi.sociallist?fref=ts"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2dAtAX3.png"/></a>
    </td>

    <td class = "greekgod">
        <h4 align = "center">Greek God</h4>
        <p align="center">On October 18th 2014, brother Anthony Leighton will be representing us in this years Greek God competition. All proceeds go to the Elizabeth Glazier Pediatric Aids Foundation.</p>

        <a href="https://www.payitsquare.com/collect-page/46106"><div class="donate-button">
        <p>Donate!</p>
        </div></a>

    </td>

    <td class = "kovacs">
        <h4 align="center">Kovacs Color Run</h4>
        <p align="center">The 5th Annual Steve Kovacs Color Run will take place on October 19th 2014. All proceeds are split between the Fairview Recovery Center and Childhood Development Center.</p>
        <a href="https://www.payitsquare.com/collect-page/41430"><div class="sign-up">
        <p>Sign Up!</p>
        </div></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <div class = "footer">
        <p>© Phi Kappa Psi NY Iota Chapter. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```
html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    margin:0 auto;

}

.logo{
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.chapter-logo {
    float:right;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

/* Start MENU styling*/

.menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 ;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both
}

ul.menu {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.menu > li {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    border-style:1px #22674A;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
}

/*sub menu styling*/

ul.menu li:first-child a {
    border-left:none;
}

ul.menu ul li:first-child {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #22674A;
}

ul.menu ul li:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #22674A;
}

ul.menu ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}

ul.menu ul li a {
    border:none;
}
ul.menu ul {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    border-left:none;
    border:solid 1px #22674A;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;

}
ul.menu a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: #22674A;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A; 
}
ul.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}

/* End MENU styling */
/* Banner Styling*/
.index {
    height:400px;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/RI05og7.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 400px;
}

.letter{
    width:460px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:20px;
    line-height:1.75em;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif
}

h4 {
    color:#22674A;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
}

/*End of Banner Styling*/

/*News Styling*/

.news {
    width:1000px;
}

.news-section {
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.greekgod {
    width:300px;
    height:220px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    text-align:center;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.donate-button {
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    border:3px solid black;
    background:#22674A;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:65px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif
}

.kovacs {
    width:300px;
    height:220px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    float:left;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding:5px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif
}

.sign-up {
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    border:3px solid black;
    background:#22674A;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:65px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif
}

.social{
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:300px;
    height:220px;
    margin-right:30px;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    padding:5px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif

}

.social a {
    padding:20px;
}

.social h4 {
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:none;

}

.footer {
height:50px;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
background-color:black;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}

.footer p {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

*FIDDLE*

http://jsfiddle.net/18468f07/

Comment: Your fiddle works. What's the issue? Is it just a specific browser?

Comment: The footer stays at the bottom inside your fiddle.

Comment: @3rror404 that is strange. Im using grunt server to view my code on google chrome and it is not staying at the bottom while viewing it

Comment: Your code seems fine   you have correctly set the .footer to absolute and bottom 0.  For the .new-section I would suggest a margin-bottom instead of the padding.

Comment: @Andrex check out my site bingphipsi.com. The footer is not showing up correctly or staying at the bottom. I uploaded this exact code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your layout I inspected it and that might have caused it.  Try this instead,  just move the footer div outside of the wrapper div so that they would be on the same label

You can also use position: fixed to make it stick there is you want.

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<div class = "footer">
          <p>© Phi Kappa Psi NY Iota Chapter. All Rights     Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

And in the css

```
Div#wrapper {
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

That should solve it.

Sorry can't format using mobile here.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now that I have it fixed to the bottom, how do I make it where it does not go past my content and overlap it?

Comment: Did you use position fixed?  If so is does overlap other elements because it's being posititiom relatice to the screen size I guess not so sure about this part.

Answer (score 0):

You could add bottom padding to the `#wrapper` element so the padding would contain the height of the footer and some space between the upper elements.  That's if you don't want to change the current structure.